# How to change tinyMCE editor value to return html element only

Tags: tinymce

I have a problem with the TinyMCE editor that I'd like to fix.

The tinymce editor converts to `[b]content[/b]` for bold text instead of `<strong>content</strong>` or `<b>content</b>`

All inline elements also do the same. including; img, italic, URL, etc.

I have checked the doc and search google, but, I'm not getting any useful answers. I'd appreciate it if anyone can be able to help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely running the `bbcode` plugin with TinyMCE.  If you stop running that plugin TinyMCE will provide you with HTML and not bbcode markup.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/bbcode/

Comment: Thanks very much. You saved me. I was literally adding plugins without knowing what it does